# Does there exists an entire function with the following property: $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)= \frac{n^4}{1+n^4}, n =1,2,...$

Tags: complex-analysis

Could anyone advise me on how to use the Identity theorem to determine whether there exists an entire function with the following property: $f\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)= \dfrac{n^4}{1+n^4}, n =1,2,...$

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**: For $n \ne 0$, $$f\left(\dfrac1n\right)=\dfrac{n^4}{1+n^4} = \dfrac 1{1 + \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^4}$$

Note that $0$ is a limit point of this function.

---

The identity theorem states that if $f$ and $g$ are analytic in a domain $D$ and $f(z) = g(z)$ for all $z \in S \subseteq D $ where $S$ has a limit point in $D$, then $f=g$ throughout $D$.

Let $$g(z) = \dfrac{1}{1+z^4}\\S = \left\{\frac 1n : n \in \mathbb N\right\}\cup \{0\}\\D=\mathbb C \setminus\{z \in \mathbb C : z^4 = -1\}$$.

Can you use the identity theorem to show that $f=g$ on $D$? Can $f$ be entire?

Comment: This means $f(0)= \lim_{\ n \to \infty}f(\dfrac{1}{n})= 1 $

Comment: Yes that's true - do you see how to finish or do you need a further hint?

Comment: So I should try to show $f'(0)$ doesn't exist?

Comment: I've added to the answer - is it clearer now?

Answer (score 0):

@Mathmo123: Thank you for the help! Based on your suggestion, we have $\text{Res}_{z=z_j}f(z)=0,$ where $(z_j)^4+1=0, j=1,2,3,4.$ Hence, $g$ can be extended to $f$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and this contradicts that $g$ is not entire.

Also, here is my alternative approach  to the original problem: Suppose $f$ is entire. Consider $h:=f-1$. Since $h(0)= 0$ and $h$ is entire,  there exists entire function $g$ and $k \geq 0$ such that $h(z)=z^kg(z),$ where $g(0) \neq 0.$

Now, ${\lim}_{\ n \to \infty}\ h \left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\dfrac{1}{h\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)}=1 \neq {\lim}_{\ n \to \infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^kg\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\dfrac{1}{h\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)} \in \{0, -\infty\}$