# Uniqueness Theorem Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am having some trouble solving the following question for my practical final.

> Does there exist an entire function f : C → C s.t. $f(1/n) = \frac{n^2}{n^2 + 1 }$ for all n in N

I don't think there exists an entire function. I know we have to use the uniqueness principle. My attempt to prove this is by contradiction:

So I know that $f(0)$ = $\lim\limits_{x \to inf} \ f(1/n)$ = 1

Now let the set E be the {0} U { 1/n} which has a limit point and let $g(z) = \frac{1/z^2}{1/z^2 + 1 }$ which has a singularity at - i and + i. I am not sure how to proceed. Thank you!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901914/does-there-exists-an-entire-function-with-the-following-property-f-left-frac for a very similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted yourself, $g(z) = \dfrac {1/z^2}{1/z^2+1} = \dfrac {1}{z^2+1}$ is already a meromorphic function which satisfies your condition, and it has poles at $\pm i$. If there were an entire function $f$ which also satisfied your condition, then it would agree with $g$ on $\{\frac 1n + 0i | n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{0 \}$. Thus it would have to agree with $g$ on a set with a limit point in $\mathbb{C}$, so by analytic continuation, $f$ must be $g$ itself; thus it cannot be entire.

Comment: I think my issue is the uniqueness principle. The principle states that if g and f are analytic on D and f(z)=g(z) for all z ∈ E that has a non-isolated singularity point, then  f(z)=g(z) for all z ∈ D. My issue is g(0) makes sense. f(1/0) doesn't. How can we say f must be g itself? Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Jack There is a mistake in your statement of the uniqueness principle, 
non-isolated singularity point" should be replaced by "limit point". As you said, $g(0)$ makes sense, and equals $1$; so you're right that we need to have $f(0)=1$ also; but this is not $f(1/0)$ as you say, it's $f("1/ \infty)$. Recall that one property of continuous functions is that if $x_n$ is a sequence in the domain converging to $x$, then the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$. If we set $x_n = 1/n$, we see that $x_n \to 0$, so $f(x_n) = \dfrac {n^2}{n^2+1} \to f(0)$. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(z)=(1+z^{2})f(z)-1$. Then $g(\frac 1 n)=0$ for all $n$ so $g(z)=0$ for all $z$. Hence $f(z)=\frac 1 {1+z^{2}}$ which has poles at $\pm i$. Hence you cannot have an entire function satisfying the given property.